# Is the os.path.join(dir, filename) needed here?

Tags: python, path

I'm just doing a bunch of [Python exercises](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/exercises/copy-special.html) and there is an exercise where you should. given a directory name, iterate over the 'special files' (containing the pattern __\w+__) and output their absolute paths.

Here's my code:

```
def get_special_paths(dir):
  filenames = os.listdir(dir)

  for filename in filenames:
    if re.search(r'__\w+__', filename):
      print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, filename))
```

I joined the dir and filename as suggest in the examples but I don't see while the join() is needed. If I don't join the filename + dir, and instead pass abspath() only the filename, the output would be the same.

Comment: as soon as you change `dir` to anything useful it won't work w/o `os.path.join`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I don't join the filename + dir, and instead pass abspath() only the filename, the output would be the same.

Only if `dir` equals the current working directory, which is not necessarily the case. Either you need the join, or `get_special_paths` should not take an argument, and instead assume `dir = os.getcwd()`.

Comment: +1 That's it. Only tried out the example by using . as the given dir.